# How to connect Linux Firewall IP whitelisting with database?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, debian, firewall

The problem is my dedicated box is getting ddosed. I would like to setup Linux firewall that would whitelist the ip addresses that would be listed in the database.

Basically the process should be - user connects to our website. The ip adresses gets logged and is sent to the application server for whitelisting.

The only part that I am not aware how to do on Linux is how to update the firewall ( iptables I assume, I am not familiar with different solutions) in realtime to block or allow specific ips

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better solution in your case is the combination of iptables and ipset. You don't need to change the iptables rule set every time, just run 'ipset add ...' to allow an ip address.

Create the db_allow ip list with default entry ttl 3600 seconds. After entry ttl timeout has expired, the ip address will be removed.

```
ipset create db_allow hash:ip counters timeout 3600
```

Inside the iptables rule set you need two additional rules. Remember, the order of rules is very important.

```
# pass connections from allowed addresses in db_allow ipset
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m set --match-set db_allow src -j ACCEPT
# block connections from other addresses
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Inside scripts to allow an ip address you just run `ipset add db_allow <ip> timeout <ttl>`.
To remove an ip address from the allow list run `ipset -! del db_allow <ip>`. Run `ipset list db_allow` command to list the allowed ip addresses.

Also, better use the iptables-save / iptables-restore / iptables-apply instead run of iptables commands from scripts or manually. Ipset lists aren't being stored between reboots, so you need a startup script to create / restore they before iptables rule set creating / restoring.